# Elegant way to select the color for a particular segment of a line plot?

Tags: r, plot, line-plot

For a list of *n* pairs of coordinates *x,y* is there a way of plotting the line between different points on a specific color?

The solution I've implemented so far is not to use the *plot* function but *lines* selecting the range for which I want the color. Here an example:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- rnorm(100,1,100)
plot(x,y ,type='n')
lines(x[1:50],y[1:50], col='red')
lines(x[50:60],y[50:60], col='black')
lines(x[60:100],y[60:100], col='red')
```

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, one way of doing this is to use `ggplot`.

`ggplot` requires your data to be in `data.frame` format. In this `data.frame` I add a column `col` that indicates your desired colour.  The plot is then constructed with `ggplot`, `geom_line`, and `scale_colour_identity` since the col variable is already a colour:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100,1,100),
  col = c(rep("red", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("red", 40))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=col, group=1)) + 
  scale_colour_identity()
```

[image]

More generally, each line segment can be a different colour.  In the next example I map colour to the x value, giving a plot that smoothly changes colour from blue to red:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100,1,100)
)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=x))
```

[image]

---

And if you insist on using base graphics, then use `segments` as follows:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100,1,100),
  col = c(rep("red", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("red", 40))
)

plot(df$x, df$y, type="n")
for(i in 1:(length(df$x)-1)){
  segments(df$x[i], df$y[i], df$x[i+1], df$y[i+1], col=df$col[i])
}
```

[image]

Comment: What, no `lattice` solution? ;)

Comment: Regarding the segments solution this uses for loop, which is the same as calling `lines` multiple times as OP did. You could use more elegant way: `with(df, segments(head(x, -1), head(y, -1), x[-1], y[-1], rep(c("red", "blue", "green"), c(50, 10, 40))))`.

Comment: @joran: I know you were in jest, but lattice does seem to get short shrift around here.  See my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Andrie, the gradient example will also be very useful for my work.

Answer (score 4):

For @joran and other lattice fans...

```
xyplot(y~x, data=df, panel=function(x,y,subscripts, groups, ...) {
  for(k in seq_len(length(subscripts)-1)) {
    i <- subscripts[k]
    j <- subscripts[k+1]
    panel.segments(df$x[i], df$y[i], df$x[j], df$y[j], col=df$col[i])
  }
})
```

Unfortunately I don't know of a slick way of doing it, so it's basically wrapping the base solution into a panel function.  The above works correctly when using a `|` to split by groups, for example, `y~x|a`, with an `a` variable as here:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1:100,
  y = rnorm(100,1,100),
  col = c(rep("red", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("red", 40)),
  a = 1:2
)
```

To use `group=` as well, you'd need the following:

```
xyplot(y~x, group=a, data=df, panel=function(x,y,subscripts, groups, ...) {
  if(missing(groups)) { groups <- rep(1, length(subscripts)) }
  grps <- split(subscripts, groups)
  for(grp in grps) {
    for(k in seq_len(length(grp)-1)) {
      i <- grp[k]
      j <- grp[k+1]
      panel.segments(df$x[i], df$y[i], df$x[j], df$y[j], col=df$col[i])
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 4):

One-liner using just the base libraries:

```
segments(head(x, -1), head(y, -1), x[-1], y[-1], rep(c("red", "black", "red"), c(49, 10, 40)))
```

(inspired by [Andrie's usage of segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744379/is-there-a-simple-way-of-selecting-the-color-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-line-p/7744707#7744707), see hist post and the discussion there)

Interestingly, it could be shortened to this:

```
segments(head(x, -1), head(y, -1), x[-1], y[-1], rep(c("red", "black"), c(49, 10)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to set the color based on the y-values rather than the x-values, use `plotrix::clplot` .  It's a fantastic, wonderful, superduper function.  Disclaimer: I wrote it :-) .   clplot() thus highlights regions of your data where y takes on specified ranges of values.
As a side note: you can expand on Chase's comment as:

```
plot(x,y,t='p', col=colorlist[some_function_of_x])
```

where colorlist is a vector of colors or colornames or whatever, and you pick an algorithm that matches your needs.  The first of Andrie's plots could be done with
    `colorlist=c('red','black')`
and
    `plot(x,y,t='p', col=colorlist[1+(abs(x-55)<=5)])`

Answer (score 0):

In base library, I don't think so (however, I cannot speak for ggplot etc.). Looking at the `lines` function and trying to supply col as a vector...: it doesn't work. I would do it the same way as you.

**EDIT after discussion with Andrie** and inspired by [his post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744379/is-there-a-simple-way-of-selecting-the-color-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-line-p/7744707#7744707): you can use `segments()` to do it in one call, see the  discussion there.

Comment: Though interestingly, plots of type `p` do work in this fashion. Consider: `plot(x,y, type = "p", col = ifelse(x < 10, "pink", "green"))`.

Comment: Base graphics: `help(plotrix::color.scale.lines)`

Comment: @DWin: this I'm not calling base (you have to load plotrix package for that...)

Comment: I've added a base R solution to my answer: just use `segments` instead of lines

Comment: @Andrie, yes, but you use a for loop - that would be also possible with lines too.