# Scatterplot with color groups - base R plot

Tags: r

I have a simple scatter plot

```
x<-rnorm(100)
y<-rnorm(100)
z<-rnorm(100)
```

I want to plot the `plot(x,y)` but the color of the points should be color coded based on `z`.

Also, I would like to have the ability to define how many groups (and thus colours) `z` should have. And that this grouping should be resistant to outliers (maybe split the `z` density into `n` equal density groups).

Till now I do this manually, is there any way to do this automatically?

**Note:** I want to do this with base R not with `ggplot`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass a vector of colours to the `col` parameter, so it is just a matter of defining your `z` groups in a way that makes sense for your application. There is the `cut()` function in base, or `cut2()` in Hmisc which offers a bit more flexibility. To assist in picking reasonable colour palettes, the [RColorBrewer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RColorBrewer/index.html) package is invaluable. Here's a quick example after defining `x,y,z`:

```
z.cols <- cut(z, 3, labels = c("pink", "green", "yellow"))
plot(x,y, col = as.character(z.cols), pch = 16)
```

[image]

You can obviously add a `legend` manually. Unfortunately, I don't think all types of plots accept vectors for the `col` argument, but `type = "p"` obviously works. For instance, `plot(x,y, type = "l", col = as.character(z.cols))` comes out as a single colour for me. For these plots, you can add different colours with `lines()` or `segments()` or whatever the low level plotting command you need to use is. See the answer by @Andrie for doing this with `type = "l"` plots in base graphics [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744379/elegant-way-to-select-the-color-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-line-plot/7744708#comment9425739_7744708).

Comment: Does cut() split in equal content intervals?

Comment: @ECII - not by default. `Hmisc:::cut2()` provides the `m` argument which sets the minimum number of observations in each group makes this easy however. Something like `z.cols2 <- cut2(z, m = length(z) / 3)` should do the trick.

Comment: Shouldn't the g argument in cut2 be better? cut2(z, g=3) ?

Comment: As a side note: if you want to set your colors based on the y-values, obviously just put y instead of z into those `cut` tools.

Comment: @ECII - probably 6 in one, 1/2 dozen in the other...I've always used the `m` argument before, but you're right that `g` is probably more aptly suited for this task. Thanks for the heads up!