# R - If else statement within for loop

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, plot

I have a data frame with 3 columns of data that I would like to plot separately - 3 plots. The data has NA in it (in different places within the 3 columns). I basically want to interpolate the missing values and plot that segment of the line (multiple sections) in red and the remainder of the line black.

I have managed to use 'zoo' to create the interpolated data but am unsure how then to plot this data point a different colour. I have found the following [Elegant way to select the color for a particular segment of a line plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744379/elegant-way-to-select-the-color-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-line-plot)
but was thinking I could use a for loop with if else statement to create the colour column as advised in the link - I would need 3 separate colour columns as I have 3 datasets.

Appreciate any help - cannot really provide an example as I'm unsure where to start! Thanks

Comment: I suggest you prepare a small reproducible example. Here are a few tips on how to proceed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It's almost always the case the people coming to R from the SAS or SPSS work incorrectly reach for a `for( ){if ( ) {} else{} }` when they should be first looking at `?ifelse`.

Comment: Thanks BondedDust - I made it far too complicated I agree. This is the code I used for this if anyone is interested                UN.GRACE$Col <- ifelse(is.na(UN.GRACE[2:4]), "red", "black")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution. It assumes that the `NA`s are still present in the original data. These will be omitted in the first `plot()` command. The function then loops over just the `NA`s.

You will probably get finer control if you take the `plot()` command out of the function. As written, "..." gets passed to `plot()` and a `type = "b"` graph is mimicked - but it's trivial to change it to whatever you want.

```
# Function to plot interpolated valules in specified colours.
PlotIntrps <- function(exxes, wyes, int_wyes, int_pt = "red", int_ln = "grey",
      goodcol = "darkgreen", ptch = 20, ...) {

  plot(exxes, wyes, type = "b", col = goodcol, pch = ptch, ...)

  nas <- which(is.na(wyes))
  enn <- length(wyes)

  for (idx in seq(nas)) {
    points(exxes[nas[idx]], int_wyes[idx], col = int_pt, pch = ptch)
    lines(
      x = c(exxes[max(nas[idx] - 1, 1)], exxes[nas[idx]],
        exxes[min(nas[idx] + 1, enn)]),
      y = c(wyes[max(nas[idx] - 1, 1)], int_wyes[idx],
        wyes[min(nas[idx] + 1, enn)]),
      col = int_ln, type = "c")

    # Only needed if you have 2 (or more) contiguous NAs (interpolations)
    wyes[nas[idx]] <- int_wyes[idx]
  }
}

# Dummy data (jitter() for some noise)
x_data <- 1:12
y_data <- jitter(c(12, 11, NA, 9:7, NA, NA, 4:1), factor = 3)
interpolations <- c(10, 6, 5)

PlotIntrps(exxes = x_data, wyes = y_data, int_wyes = interpolations, 
  main = "Interpolations in pretty colours!",
  ylab = "Didn't manage to get all of these")
```

Cheers.