# reorder legend of multiple line plot with segment using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, line-plot

I have a multiple line plot with a segment of each line highlighted the same way as discussed 
   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7744379/elegant-way-to-select-the-color-for-a-particular-segment-of-a-line-plot/7744707).
Here is the reproducible example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,y1 = rnorm(100,1,100),y2=rnorm(100,5,50),y3=rnorm(100,10,500),y4=rnorm(100,1,200),col1 = c(rep("red", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("red", 40)),col2=c(rep("blue", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("blue", 40)),col3=c(rep("orange", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("orange", 40)),col4=c(rep("cyan", 50), rep("black", 10), rep("cyan", 40)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + geom_line(aes(colour=col1, group=1))+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2,col=col2,group=1))+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y3,col=col3,group=1))+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,colour=col4, group=1))+geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,col=col4,group=1))+scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue","red","orange","cyan"),labels=c("new","s1on","s2off","s2_on","s1_off"),name="")
```

This gives the order of the items in the legend as shown in the image below. I want to reorder them. Since each line has a segment and each segment has the same color "black", I am not able to use `breaks` argument  in `scale_color_manual` as it requires 5 values and the plot is plotted for 4 columns in the dataframe. How can I reorder the items in the legend in the order s1on, s2on, s1_off, s2_off and new? 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=col1, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2,col=col2,group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y3,col=col3,group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,colour=col4, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,col=col4,group=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("blue","orange","cyan","red","black"),
                     values=c("blue" = "blue", "red" = "red","orange" = "orange","cyan" = "cyan","black" = "black"),
                     labels=c("s1on","s2_on","s1_off","s2off","new"),name="")
```

You can use `breaks` to reorder the legend. The `values` argument is mapping the right color to the right value.

It is easier for me to see if the values in `df` are different than the colors you want

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
             y1 = rnorm(100,1,100),
             y2=rnorm(100,5,50),
             y3=rnorm(100,10,500),
             y4=rnorm(100,1,200),
             col1 = c(rep("rrr", 50), 
                      rep("bbb", 10), 
                      rep("rrr", 40)),
             col2=c(rep("blbl", 50), 
                    rep("bbb", 10), 
                    rep("blbl", 40)),
             col3=c(rep("ooo", 50),
                    rep("bbb", 10), 
                    rep("ooo", 40)),
             col4=c(rep("ccc", 50), 
                    rep("bbb", 10), 
                    rep("ccc", 40)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour=col1, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y2,col=col2,group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y3,col=col3,group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,colour=col4, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x, y=y4,col=col4,group=1)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("blbl","ooo","ccc","rrr","bbb"),
                 values=c("blbl" = "blue", "rrr" = "red","ooo" = "orange","ccc" = "cyan","bbb" = "black"),
                 labels=c("s1on","s2_on","s1_off","s2off","new"),name="")
```

Comment: ah..it was not so difficult! It didn't come to my mind that I could define it this way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank.You.So.Much.